# Only insert when exists (with the same ID)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with these fields:

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
```

This is actually a WordPress *postmeta* table.

Some of posts have a *postmeta* entry where meta_key is `_price`. What I need is to loop through the table, and **INSERT another row**, with meta_key = `_regular_price`, same post_id and same meta_value.

So I check if a *postmeta* entry with that meta_key exists, and add another one with different meta_key. Sounds simple, but how do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will insert new rows with the existing post_id and the meta_key value '_regular_price' for all posts that have a meta_key = '_price'. The meta_id and meta_value columns will be null or whatever their default values are (if there's any default constraints).

```
insert postmeta (post_id, meta_key)
select post_id, '_regular_price' from postmeta p1
where exists (select 1 from postmeta where meta_key = '_price' and p1.post_id = post_id)
```

If you intend to run it more than once you might want to add a condition checking that there doesn't already exists a '_regular_price' meta_key:

```
and not exists (select 1 from postmeta where meta_key = '_regular_price' and p1.post_id = post_id)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eaaf/1)

Comment: that could probably work... how do I set meta_value to the same value?

Comment: Just add in the column in the insert and select: `insert postmeta (meta_id, post_id, meta_key) select meta_id, post_id, '_regular_price' from `

Comment: That is, if the meta_id isn't auto-incrementing. I don't know what the `postmeta` table looks like.

Comment: I also had to add an additional `where` statement, but overall you gave me a right direction. thanks for that. (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bef6)

Comment: @Uhehesh Ah yeah, you would have gotten duplicate rows if there was any other meta_key for the same post_id; I didn't think of that.